# PHP - Skip in array

Tags: php, arrays

I got the following php array from an api/curl request.

```
[1]=>
  array(11) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "12032017"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "0525"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "12032017-1118"
    [3]=>
    string(10) "ER-TALLINN"
    [4]=>
    string(5) "A8XS5"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [6]=>
    string(9) "Discharge"
    [7]=>
    string(4) "4955"
    [8]=>
    string(3) "112"
    [9]=>
    string(12) "120320170822"
    [10]=>
    string(17) "UNIFEEDER-GERMANY"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Load"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "4956"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "112"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "1318"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "12032017-1605"
    [2]=>
    string(17) "BERNHARD-SCHEPERS"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "V2HS6"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [5]=>
    string(9) "Discharge"
    [6]=>
    string(4) "4953"
    [7]=>
    string(3) "169"
    [8]=>
    string(12) "120320171418"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "4"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Load"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "4954"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "169"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(9) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "1415"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "12032017-1842"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "POLLUX"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "V2GK9"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [5]=>
    string(9) "Discharge"
    [6]=>
    string(4) "4925"
    [7]=>
    string(3) "035"
    [8]=>
    string(12) "120320171615"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Load"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "4926"
    [3]=>
    string(3) "035"
  }
```

I convert this array to an html bootstrap table, this works properlay, but I want to avoid all four-element array in the foreach, because the 4 element array is broke the html table.

How can i do this?

Comment: Um, just check to see if that array has four elements and skip it?

Comment: Where is the PHP code as you tagged your question with PHP?

Comment: Post the code you are using to parse the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you just want to get rid of all 4 element arrays?, you could just pass your data to a function like so,

```
function destroy4(&$arr){
    for($i=count($arr)-1;$i>=0;$i--){
        if(count($arr[$i])==4)
            unset($arr[$i]);
    }
    $arr = array_values($arr); //restore index
}

destroy4($data);
```